# Remove XML elements based on user input

Tags: php, xml, input, element, removechild

I would like to remove a XML entry based on user input.

XML Example:

```
<YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>
<DirectoryEntry>
<Name>Test321</Name>
<Telephone>101</Telephone>
<Telephone>102</Telephone>
<Telephone>103</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
<Name>Test456</Name>
<Telephone>107</Telephone>
<Telephone>108</Telephone>
<Telephone>109</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
<DirectoryEntry>
<Name>Test789</Name>
<Telephone>000</Telephone>
<Telephone>111</Telephone>
<Telephone>222</Telephone>
</DirectoryEntry>
</YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>
```

So remove entries DirectoryEntry to the DirectoryEntry end. The entry works fine and submits the data properly formatted:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) { 
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8"); 
$xml->load("emergency.xml"); 
$rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("YealinkIPPhoneDirectory")->item(0); 
$dataTag = $xml->createElement("DirectoryEntry"); 
$aTag = $xml->createElement("Name",$_REQUEST['a']); 
$bTag = $xml->createElement("Telephone",$_REQUEST['b']); 
$cTag = $xml->createElement("Telephone",$_REQUEST['c']);
$dTag = $xml->createElement("Telephone",$_REQUEST['d']);
$dataTag->appendChild($aTag); 
$dataTag->appendChild($bTag); 
$dataTag->appendChild($cTag);
$dataTag->appendChild($dTag);
$rootTag->appendChild($dataTag); 
$xml->save("emergency.xml");
 } 
 ?> 
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="emergencycontacts.php" method="post">
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="emergencycontacts.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend> </legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
 <input class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text" name="a" /> 
 <span class="help-block">Required</span>  
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Extension</label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
 <input class="form-control input-md" value=" " type="text" name="b" /> 
 <span class="help-block">Internal</span>  
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Direct Phone Line</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
 <input class="form-control input-md" value=" " type="text" name="c" /> 
 <span class="help-block">External</span>  
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Cellular Phone</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
 <input class="form-control input-md" value=" " type="text" name="d" />
 <span class="help-block">External</span>  
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Button (Double) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" input type="submit" name="ok" value="Submit Entry" >


  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
 </form>
```

When I placed a second form below and attempted to remove the node with a foreach I go no results added or removed. The form remains in tact as it was:

```
                <p>Please fill in the below form to REMOVE a contact to the phone system.</p>

<?php 
if (isset($_REQUEST['ok2'])) { 
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8"); 
$xml->load("emergency.xml"); 
$aTag = $_POST['a'];
$xpath = new DOMXPATH($xml);
foreach($xpath->query("/YealinkIPPhone/DirectoryEntry[a = '$aTag']") as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$xml->formatoutput = true;
$xml->save("emergency.xml");
 } 
 ?> 
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="emergencycontacts.php" method="post">
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="emergencycontacts.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend> </legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
 <input class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text" name="a" /> 
 <span class="help-block">Required</span>  
  </div>
</div>

 <!-- Button (Double) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" input type="submit" name="ok2" value="Delete Entry" >
```

I searched all over and didnt find much on removal of data based on uer entry. Is there a better way to remove elements? I dont see what Im missing.

Comment: The root element was it thank you! You're correct on the evaluation of the named element. Not sure how that got reverted in my post. I appreciate the second set of eyes. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath query doesn't correspond to the XML structure :

```
/YealinkIPPhone/DirectoryEntry[a = '$aTag']
```

Namely, the root element of the XML named `YealinkIPPhoneDirectory`, not `YealinkIPPhone`. And child of `DirectoryEntry` element which value need to be evaluated is `Name` not `a` :

```
foreach($xpath->query("/YealinkIPPhoneDirectory/DirectoryEntry[Name = '$aTag']") as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/632114)</kbd>**